# savedInstanceState always null (Activity A to Activity B back to Activity A)

Tags: java, android, hashmap, bundle, onsaveinstancestate

This is a Java language project for Android application using Android Studio.

I go from `Activity A` to `Activity B` and then back to `Activity A`. Nothing is transferred from `Activity A` to `Activity B`, but on the way from `Activity B` to `Activity A` there is. Here is code taking you from `Acitvity B` to `Activity A`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent main_intent = new Intent(PeriodicTableActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    main_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    main_intent.putExtra("Element", String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
    startActivity(main_intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_fast, R.anim.fade_out_fast);
}
```

On the way back from Activity B to Activity A, I want to use `Bundle savedInstanceState` to restore a `HashMap<Integer, ElementInfo>` instead of parsing web `URL` that fills the `HashMap` in the opening of the Android application.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
       elementInfoHashMap = (HashMap<Integer, ElementInfo>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ELEMENTS");
try {
    InputStream input1 = getAssets().open("periodic_table.csv");
    elementInfoHashMap.putAll(pullElementURLData());
} catch (IOException | NetworkOnMainThreadException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is how I store my `HashMap<Integer, ElementInfo>` when I leave `Activity A`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("ELEMENTS", elementInfoHashMap);
}
```

My issue is that whenever I return to `Activity A` from `Activity B`, my `savedInstanceState` is `null`. Does anyone have an clue why `savedInstancedState` is `null` when returning from `Activity B` to `Activity A`?

Comment: You should look at startActivityForResult

Comment: @Rockney thanks this is what i was looking for. I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android